# Regex find in video tag from and until

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I have this video tag:

```
<video src="https://videosource.com" x-webkit-airplay="allow"></video>
```

I use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser like this:

```
$html = str_get_html($output);

$output2 = $html->find('video', 0);

preg_match('/\src:"(.*?)\"/', $output2, $match);
```

But is return me empty value. How I can get https://videosource.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing html with regex is not a good idea but since you have video tag which doesn't have nesting so you can use it here.

You slightly need to correct your regex and use this,

```
src="([^"]*?)"
```

Demo,

https://regex101.com/r/HPGzRq/1

Edit1:

Here is the kind of php code you can use,

```
$output2 = '<video src="https://videosource.com" x-webkit-airplay="allow"></video>';
preg_match('/src=\"([^\"]*?)\"/', $output2, $match);
print($match[1]);
```

$match[1] captures and returns group 1 in the regex and the output of these lines is,

```
https://videosource.com
```

Comment: I have changed to: `$data = preg_match('src="([^"]*?)"', $output2, $match);
` and output is empty!

Comment: I have added sample php code that shows how you can capture group 1 in regex to get the url.